# Make string more user friendly/readable in bash script

Tags: bash

I've been trying to convert the following string into a more readable and usable form in a bash script. Certain parts are not static.

```
(<font color='whisper'>[ <name shortname='UserName' src='whisper-from'>UserName</name> whispers, "test" to you. ]</font>
```

A lot of the stuff in fact is not static. Basically, I want the end result to look like:

```
([UserName whispers, "test" to you. ]
```

I have done this time and time again in Java, PHP, and even VB6. However I am new to bash scripts, and can't seem to get it to work.

Could someone help me convert this Java code to bash script?

```
 data = MyString.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
 data = MyString.replaceAll("&lt;", "<");
 data = MyString.replaceAll("&gt;", ">");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your string formatting has been messed up by the Stack Overflow editor. I've indented your strings to prevent rendering of HTML entities, but you've just undone most of that edit... you have to indent your code by four spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can use pattern substitution.  Let's start with this string:

```
$ s='&lt;Name&gt;'
```

And, let's do substitutions on it:

```
$ s="${s//&lt;/<}"
$ s="${s//&gt;/>}"
$ echo "$s"
<Name>
```

Bash works on globs.  If you need regular expressions, try sed:

```
$ s='&lt;Name&gt;'
$ echo "$s" | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>/<>/g'
<>
```

In a more complex example:

```
$ MyStr='(<font color='whisper'>[ <name shortname='UserName' src='whisper-from'>UserName</name> whispers, "test" to you. ]</font>'
$ echo "$MyStr" | sed 's/&lt;/</g; s/&gt;/>/g; s/<[^>]*>//g'
([ UserName whispers, "test" to you. ]
```

Comment: the complexed example seems to work exactly as i needed. I was looking at sed, but just wasn't able to wrap my head around how to do the regex in bash. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed` by itself or, since you mentioned `bash`, use `sed` within a `bash` script (for example `b.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's/&gt;/>/g' | sed 's/&lt;/</g' | sed 's/<.*?>//g'
```

Input data (for example `b.txt` file):

```
asdasdasdds<.*?>dasdasassxrh
sadaswqqw&lt;ssadasdasdsdvvxc
sadssadadsads&gt;dsdsdewpppp
```

Output results:

```
asdasdasddsdasdasassxrh
sadaswqqw<ssadasdasdsdvvxc
sadssadadsads>dsdsdewpppp
```

Usage:

```
b.sh < b.txt
```

NOTE: I broke each replace all into separate `sed` calls in case you wanted to modify or add more formatting changes.